# Fast Search On FAT32/NTFS File System

Tags: search, filesystems, ntfs, fat32

I'm writing a program that searches through the entire file system by file name and file contents (plain text). Is there any algorithm or open source project that could make the search very fast? I'm doing this on Windows with `FAT/NTFS` file systems and I don't want indexing.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about it since your algorithm will necessarily be limited by hard disk speed, unless it's absolutely terrible.

Comment: thanks @Wug, i guess i'll have to enumerating all files and pray for a fast disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded a NTFS searcher (named NTFS-Search) on SourceForce and it does the job very well! It first reads the 'FAT'once and after that it is incredibly fast. Only the interface is in German.

You can download the source with SVN:

```
svn co https://ntfs-search.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ntfs-search
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only searching by file name / file attributes / file date, the "magic" method to have the best performances is to manually "parse" the File Allocation Table (if filesystem is FAT) and the Master File Table (if filesystem is NTFS).

It's not too hard for the FAT filesystem as it's quite simple and well documented, but it's more difficult for NTFS, as the filesystem is much more complicated and not-so-well documented.

If you also want to search for file content, then there is no way but enumerating all files the reading through their content. You'll always be limited by the disk read speed, you can't optimize that without indexing file content.

Comment: Thanks @ken2k. Performance limited by disk read speed is what I thought, since I do need to search for file content. Btw do you know if there is any ready-made searching algorithms/frameworks that i could take advantage of? I asked google and he said nothing helpful.

Comment: Programmatically digging through the file table of the file system is not something you should be doing.  Use your operating system's provided interface to read files.

Comment: @Wug It's not recommended, but if the search speed (based on file name/attributes only) is the main requirement, it's an option