# File search taking too long

Tags: vb.net

We need to free up some space on one of our network HDD. The directory in question has 526GB of data, 180914 files in 13555 directories.

So I wrote the code to find copies of files. The user specifies the file to find and the app finds all instances of the file. It works fine except it takes minutes. I am not surprised at this, but the same search in windows explorer is faster.

The reason I think this is because I run my app then perform the same search in Windows Explorer searching the same folder for the same file.

There is one difference and I just don't know how much it would matter...

Because some of the searched for files have identical names (say OPERATIONS MANUAL.PDF) but are different, I compare size when I get a hit. SO the search finds a file and I check the file size only returning those with identical names and file sizes.

I get 5 in a particular search and explorer returns 74.

My app takes 2 minutes and explorer takes 1 minute.

Is there anything I can do to be more efficient? I would expect I should be able to approximate what explorer gets for performance.

Here is the code...

```
'find all instances of the file
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'first clear the listbox
        LB_Files.Items.Clear()


        'set the lbel text for the list box
        Label1.Text = "Finding all instances of:  " & TB_File.Text & " in directory:  " & TB_Drive.Text & " and all sub-driectories... PLEASE STAND BY"
        'make sure the label updates
        Me.Refresh()

        'run through and find each file and add it to the listbox
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(TB_Drive.Text, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, TB_File.Text)

            'check if the file is a shortcut and if it is do nothing
            If foundFile.Contains(".lnk") Then

            Else

                Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo
                infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundFile)
                newfilesize = infoReader.Length
                'MsgBox("The old file size is: " & oldfilesize & ",  and the new file size is:  " & newfilesize)
                'for each file that is not a shortcut, add it to the list box

                'check if the file sizes match, don't want to add a file if it is not the same file
                If newfilesize = oldfilesize Then

                    LB_Files.Items.Add(foundFile)
                    'update the file count
                    count = count + 1
                    newfilesize = 0

                End If
                'reset the newfilesize
                newfilesize = 0
            End If


        Next
        'once we find all the files, change the lable to say how many we have.
        Label1.Text = "Found " & count.ToString & " instances of " & TB_File.Text & "."

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a windows server?

If so, then I would not bother with an iterative search, and would learn more about the filesystem.  You can find files much quicker by searching an index.

have a look at [Fast Search On FAT32/NTFS File System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824325/fast-search-on-fat32-ntfs-file-system)

from the accepted answer you will find a sourceforge project that indexes the drive - convert this part to vb and presto a super quick way of searching the files.  Alternatively you could use one of the many free tools for doing exactly this.